# Android. Do I need to dispose Maybe inside onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2

I'm executing a heavy request inside `MayBe` observable in my adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final RealmArticle obj = getItem(position);
    int idTask = obj.getIdTask();

    Disposable mayBeCount = Maybe.fromCallable(()->
        {
            Realm bgInstance = Realm.getInstance(Realm.getDefaultInstance().getConfiguration());
            return bgInstance.where(RealmArticle.class).findAll().where().equalTo("idTask", idTask).equalTo("completed", true).count()
        })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(res->{
                        holder.row_count.setText(res);
                        this.notifyItemChanged(position);
            },
                    throwable -> Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s, %s", "Can not get items count", throwable.getMessage())));
}
```

The question is: Should I dispose the `mayBeCount`? If so, in what life cycle moment is it better to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onViewDetachedFromWindow` to cancel the operation hopefully. Therefore I would add the `Disposable` as an attribute to your viewholder.

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(MyViewHolder holder) {
    holder.mayBeCount.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is the way. Thanks!